# Audio to blob and POST to cloudinary issue

Tags: reactjs, audio, axios, blob, cloudinary

I'm new in coding and I'm practicing with a little project.
The idea is to record an audio from the user and post it to cloudinary.
I'm able to record with this code

```js
const audioType = 'audio/webm'
async startRecording(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    this.audio.srcObject = stream
    this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
      mimeType: audioType,
    })
    this.chunks = []
    this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = e => {
      if (e.data && e.data.size > 0) {
        this.chunks.push(e.data)
      }
    }
    this.chunks = []
    this.mediaRecorder.start(10)
    this.setState({ recording: true })
  }
```

To stop the recording, update state and trigger Save with this code:

```js
stopRecording(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.mediaRecorder.stop()
    this.setState({ recording: false })
    this.saveAudio()
  }
```

I save the file so I can display it on browser, I make a blob:

```js
saveAudio() {
    const audioBlob = new Blob(this.chunks, { type: audioType })
    const audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob)
    const audios = this.state.audios.concat([audioURL])
    this.setState({ audios })
    this.handleUpload()
  }
```

And finally the problem, the uploading function to cloudinary:

```js
async handleUpload () {
    const data = new FormData()
    data.append('audio', this.audioBlob)
    data.append('upload_preset', uploadPreset)
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(uploadUrl, data)
      this.setState({
        audioStatePath: res.data.secure_url,
      })
      console.log(res.data.secure_url)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
```

I've been looking for a solution for this for days, trying other code and looking for other people's post.
It's similar to the problem talked here
[Uploading Audio to Cloudinary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60019838/uploading-audio-to-cloudinary)

With the only difference that I don't understand that code.
Sorry for the already asked question, but it's hard at the beginning...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The blob you want to upload into Cloudinary should be sent in the parameter called `file`. So you will want to replace:

```
data.append('audio', this.audioBlob)
```

With:

```
data.append('file', this.audioBlob)
```

In addition, you will want to double-check the value of your `uploadUrl` which should be in the following format (replacing cloud_name with your actual one): `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/cloud_name_here/upload`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've tried as you suggested, but I still get 'Bad Request'. UploadUrl has cloudinaryLink assigned to it

Comment: I've tried in a different document setting up an input and uploading an audio recorded from this app and it successfully upload it to cloudinary.
I guess the problem is in the upload function somehow

Comment: What was the error message in the response from Cloudinary for the failed upload?

Comment: xhr.js:177 POST https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/MY_LINK/video/upload 400 (Bad Request).
If I check the audioBlob from the upload app I get Undefined.
If I check it from the saveAudio function I get the blob result. So I guess the upload function doesn't get the data

Answer (score 0):

I was able to understand a little bit more the code in this answer, solving my issue finally!

[Uploading Audio to Cloudinary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60019838/uploading-audio-to-cloudinary)

Thanks Aleksandar!!!